# Get every point plot data information when clicked on graph core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using the core plot to draw graph but i need to show every plot point info on touch on every plot coordinate.Please help me how can i show the info my data on every plot accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should save the location and information of each plot point and check that against the touch you receive from the user. When you have drawn something on a canvas there is no way to ask it for information about a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plot delegate to get notified of the touch. There are several examples in the Plot Gallery and CPTTestApp (Mac) example apps.